# Synonym by a moderator which needs approval?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, moderators

When I look at [list of tag synonyms](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/synonyms) I see there a pending synonym [rsk-correspondence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/rsk-correspondence) $\to$ [robinson-schensted-knuth](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/robinson-schensted-knuth) and François G. Dorais♦ is listed as the creator. You can also see that this synonym is still waiting for votes [on the corresponding page](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/robinson-schensted-knuth/synonyms).

I know that regular users can suggest synonyms and in such case they need votes from other users. But AFAIK synonyms suggested by mods do not have to go through this procedure.

The FAQ on tag synonyms seems to confirm this: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710) which says: "Additionally, moderators can create synonyms as needed and have their suggestions instantly approved."<sup>1</sup>

Is this unusual exception a bug?

---

In case the situation changes, I have added screenshots below.

This is what I see [in the list of tag synonyms](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/synonyms):

[image: screenshot]

And this is from list of [synonyms for the (robinson-schensted-knuth) tag](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/robinson-schensted-knuth/synonyms):

[image: screenshot]

---

<sup>1</sup>It seems that there is an exception to this, depending on *how* the moderator created the synonym. At least according to this post: [Allow diamond moderators to create tag synonyms on their meta sites from the synonyms page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202228) (I only found the linked post after posting this question.) I should say that even after finding out about this possibility, it seems to me a bit unusual - since you can see that two synonyms were created nearly at the same time, so it does not seem very likely that for creating one of them the moderator in question would use a different way than for the other one.

Comment: I did use two different methods for the tag synonyms. The reason is that I wasn't entirely sure which direction the synonym should go, so I let the community decide what to do.

Comment: I see. So what I thought was a bug was entirely intentional. There are not that many users [who can vote on the synonym](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/robinson-schensted-knuth/topusers) (i.e. score 5 or more in the tag), but I assume it is not something urgent. (So I have removed the ([meta-tag:bug]) tag.)

Comment: I am not sure whether this question is worth keeping here. (Possibly it might have some informational value if in the future somebody sees a synonym by a mod waiting for votes, they might wonder whether it is a bug and they might find this question on meta. So in this scenario it adds some useful information.) If you post your explanation as an answer, I will accept the answer. If you think that the question is not really worth keeping around, feel free to simply delete it.